# Unable to install gnome 3.16 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: gnome

Its rebooting again and again by raising a message reebootexception:reboot in 120 seconds

Comment: Excuse me, How you install Gnome 3.16? with follow command? `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`